# Why wt always uses post and doesn't use get method?

Tags: wt

I was trying a Wt example with firebug and I see that Wt always uses POST method instead GET method. I would know if that is more efficient or if there are another way using GET instead POST.

Comment: This question is answered by the Wt developers [on their own forums here](http://redmine.webtoolkit.eu/boards/1/topics/4817) (probably to this same asker).